# Bitbucket / SourceTree authentication failure

Tags: git, bitbucket.org

On some occasions and currently NOW SourceTree will not allow me do any operations against My bitbucket repository and keeps popping up to choose a credention helper of which I have no clue which one to choose, and it seems none of them work. Even when I select no helper it keeps popping up this one.

[image]

When I disable SSL Certificate checks in settings it pops up instead a username/password dialog over an over again ,while I enter my email address and password. I also changed the password via the same dialog just in case. Nogo.

I then try to EDIT and refresh the OAUTH token.

And then magically now it works again. After 30 minutes doing the same stuff.

This seeems to happen frequently. I wonder if I need to refresh the OAUTH token on each day, if that is the solution or if it server side something / too busy / max amount of connections or something alike.

It seems like magic the moments it does not work and the moments it works.

Comment: Still no answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

SourceTree just wouldn't be SourceTree without major bugs.

Atlassian has an article about this issue [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-articles/Bug-Fix-Sourcetree-for-Windows-authentication-error-when/ba-p/1965968)

In brief:

1. Navigate to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\Sourcetree` and remove the `passwd` file.
2. If the above does not fix the issue, uninstall and reinstall SourceTree.

Comment: hallelujah, perhaps anyone else reading this, when the password is prompt, use the app password :)